# socket.io sending over only differences in a text

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am building a realtime collaborative text editor using socket.io

Currently, I am sending over the whole of the text file, every time a change is made. This is very inefficient
Instead I want to send over only the changes.

So when a user makes a change, I want to only send over the changes. Next, when another user recieves the message, how can I convert all of the changes into the full text document again.

Please take a look at the following code:
I have a variable called `text` which stores the users text.

```
var socket = io()
var text = ""
$( document ).ready(function() {
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
      text = msg
      document.getElementById("textArea").value = text
    });
  });

function onChange() { //called on change to text editor textarea
    text = document.getElementById("textArea").value

    socket.emit("message", text)
}
```

Thank you.